# ListView ArrayAdapter does not show correct data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got it to work so that it shows some data retrieved from the database in the listview. It displays 10 rows out of my db, which only has 10 rows, but the problem is, it shows it as `com.example.somename.LocationData@23157b39`. Why is this the case and how can I fix this? So the problem is in LocationHistory.java activity. It shows that strange package names on my display.

activity_location_history.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LocationHistory">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LocationsDataSource.java:

```
    // some code
    private static final String[] allColumns = {
                LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE,
                LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE,
                LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TIME};
    // some code

public List<LocationData> findAll() {
        List<LocationData> locations = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(LocationsDBOpenHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                LocationData locationdata = new LocationData();
                locationdata.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "COLUMN_ID " + locationdata.getId());
                locationdata.setLatitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE)));
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "COLUMN_LATITUDE " + locationdata.getLatitude());
                locationdata.setLongitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "COLUMN_LONGITUDE " + locationdata.getLongitude());
                locationdata.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TIME)));
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "COLUMN_TIME " + locationdata.getTime());
                locations.add(locationdata);
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "locationdata " + locationdata.toString());
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "locations " + locations.toString());
            }
        }
        return locations;
    }
```

LocationHistory.java:

```
// some code

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_history);

        datasource = new LocationsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<LocationData> locationdata = datasource.findAll();
        if (locationdata.size() == 0) {
            locationdata = datasource.findAll();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<LocationData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LocationData>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationdata);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

// some code
```

LocationData.java:

```
public class LocationData {
    private long id;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String time;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com.example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ COLUMN_ID 1
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com. example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ COLUMN_LATITUDE  21.36654189
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com. example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ COLUMN_LONGITUDE 6.945669
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com. example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ COLUMN_TIME 12:10:34 AM
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com. example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ locationdata com. example.somename.LocationData@1b6b10f7
09-18 00:16:12.614  25181-25181/com. example.somename I/EXPLORECA﹕ locations [com. example.somename.LocationData@1b6b10f7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is here

> Log.i(LOGTAG, "locationdata " + locationdata)

is actually called `Log.i(LOGTAG, "locationdata " + locationdata.toString())`. But LocationData.toString() method is not implemented and used Object.toString()

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The Log.i's I put there after that my activity showed those strange package names. I put it there to see if they would show any good data at all. So without the Log.i's, it still shows those strange package names in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
 Log.i(LOGTAG, "locationdata " + locationdata);
```

you are actually trying to convert the List locationdata list to String, you can do that for primivtive types but you have to provide your own implementation of the toString if you want to do it in your class.

please add

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return this.getId();
 }
```

and try again.

Good Luck

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The Log.i's I put there after that my activity showed those strange package names. I put it there to see if they would show any good data at all. So without the Log.i's, it still shows those strange package names in the activity.